# Creating a login based website in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, content-management-system

Im a Drupal beginner. I want to create a simple website, which has a login form. Users should be able to register on the website and then be able to login into it.
Can someone please provide some tips or point me to some resources online which can help me achieve this functionality ?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of this functionality is available out of the box with Drupal.

You can choose to have users self register, or for users to apply, subject to your approval.

You'll need to configure permissions appropriately for "Authenticated Users", but that's not hard.

The best place for you to start is the [official documentation](http://drupal.org/handbooks). I'd suggest you start with [Understanding Drupal](http://drupal.org/getting-started/before) - you need to understand the terminology and what comes out of the box in order to succeed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see how the register/login works then why not try signing up to the drupal.org community site, this should give you an ideahttp://drupal.org/

Next you will need to find out your hosts mail options - as im guessing you will want an email sent out upon registration

The login/register functionality comes in-built with drupal, you will just need to sign up as an admin yourself first and if you have the email set up correct you should be able to carry out a test registration.

There is also an acl module for group user access control http://drupal.org/project/acl

Hope it helps